# Определение или сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Чем в предложении являются однородные члены предложения:

> Там ангелов блестящая плотва **в зелёном**, **белом**, **розовом**,
>   **лиловом**.

Answer (score 2):

*Там ангелов блестящая плотва в зелёном, белом, розовом, лиловом.*

Неполное предложение с пропуском сказуемого, на которое указывает обстоятельство **там**. Ппотва ангелов (какая?) в зелёном, розовом, лиловом (одеянии). Однородные несогласованные определения.

Comment: Предложение эллиптическое вида "обстоятельство - подлежащее".  В неполном предложении сказуемое восстанавливается из контекста, а в эллиптическом могут подразумеваться разные сказуемые

Comment: Это Вы кому объясняете? Эллиптические -  разновидность неполных предложений, в которых недостающий член не восстанавливается и не подсказывается ситуацией, предыдущим контекстом, они не требуются для раскрытия смысла предложения. Только нам это не очень нужно. Главное, что пропущено сказуемое, значит, прилагательные - определения, а не сказуемые, как можно подумать.

Comment: В эллиптических предложениях  нет сказуемого, это двусоставные предложения особой структуры, поэтому нельзя сказать, что сказуемое  пропущено, как говорится у Вас.  И не знаю, почему Вы считаете их разновидностью, по-моему, каждый вид имеет СВОЁ определение.